# Add more signers to a signed document

Tags: docusignapi

I need to do this use case:

- create a Docusign envelope with one signer
- let the signer sign the document through embedded signing
- add another signer to the document, and let the other signer sign it too

Reason: it might take some time for the 2nd company to sign the document, and the exact person to sign it might not be known at the beginning yet.

Comment: If you have only 1 signer and they complete the envelope, the envelope will be marked "Completed" and will not be able to be modified at that point.  There are multiple ways to handle having an unknown recipient in a later routing order. Manage Recipients is a role that can do it through the web console. Or you could always add a temporary recipient and edit who it's going to at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

There's at least two ways to solve for this but possibly others too.

The first method is using one of the pre-built [Recipient Types](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/recipients) such as `Agent` or `Editors` or `Intermediaries`.  These recipient types have varying capabilities (i.e. some can add tabs, docs, etc. to the envelopes) but the one thing they all have in common is that they can edit recipient information such as Name and Email address for recipients that come later in the routing order.

Another method for handling this which is a slight hack but still doable is to add two recipients with routing orders 1 and 2 to the envelope at the start, the first one is the recipient whose information you already know but for the second recipient you add a fake name and a fake email address.  Once the first recipient signs the request technically gets sent to the "dummy" recipient but since it's a fake email it never gets sent to anyone.  THEN, once you finally know who the second recipient is you can do an [Envelope Correction](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Modify%20or%20Correct%20and%20Resend%20Recipient%20Information.htm?Highlight=correct) and replace the dummy recipient with the real name and email.